# C# string starts with a number regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, digits

I've been searching around for a little while to figure out how to confirm a string begins with a number. I came across a regex statement '/^\d/' which I can confirm says if starts with digit. However I can not seem to get it to work in the code below. Where did I went wrong in the statement `if(Regex.Match(info,"/^\d/"))`?

```
//String attachbody is the attachment body from an email C read into a string
string[] data = Regex.Split(attachbody, "\n");

foreach (String info in data)
{
    if (Regex.Match(info,"/^\d/"))
    {
        string[] tabbedHeaderData = Regex.Split(info, "\t");
        TicketID = tabbedHeaderData[0].ToString();
        Status = tabbedHeaderData[1].ToString();
        URL = tabbedHeaderData[2].ToString();
        InitCats = tabbedHeaderData[3].ToString();
        PostRevCats = tabbedHeaderData[4].ToString();
        ListNumClosed = tabbedHeaderData[5].ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(TicketID);
        Console.WriteLine(Status);
        Console.WriteLine(URL);
        Console.WriteLine(InitCats);
        Console.WriteLine(PostRevCats);
        Console.WriteLine(ListNumClosed);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

example data (tab delimited):
TicketID    Status  URL InitCats    PostRevCats ListNumClosed
555555  Closed  http://5555555.com/searcho      Malicious Sites 55555

Comment: can you post some example data? Have you tried the regex.match without the /'s?

Comment: Then, as above, your regex should be "^\d" no forward slashes.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. `/.../` is javascript convention for defining regular expressions. Try like this in C#:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(info, @"^\d"))
```

Also notice that you should use the [IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx) method which returns boolean or your code won't even compile.

And if you wanted to match that the string starts with one or more digits:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(info, @"^\d+"))
```

Comment: / ... / is not "javascript convention". It's perl.

Comment: @erlando, oh, pardon my ignorance then. I didn't knew this was coming from perl. Probably because I never used perl in my life :-) I just happen to use this convention in javascript.

Comment: Filed under "obscure knowledge" then.. :-) Javascript's regex engine uses perl-style regex's inline if not defined with new RegExp(...) in which case the regex should not be enclosed in /.../

Comment: Also, if you specify the regex operation in Perl, you will be able to use odd characters as delimiter - i.e. m|^\d| instead of m/^\d/ is acceptable, albeit a bit unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 43):

You don't need a regex for this.  Try

```
if (info.Length > 0 && char.IsDigit(info[0]))
{
   ...
}
```

If you want to use the regex, take out the `//` so it's just `Regex.IsMatch(info,@"^\d")`.

Comment: Thank you agent-j, this is exactly what i was looking for. Stackoverflow says i have to wait 20min to accept your answer. thanks!

Comment: agent-j i just noticed that your answer is using the regex.match option and not the regex.ismatch option. I had to give the answer to Darin because he set me straight with it. Thank you for the ground work!

Comment: This is the solution when you use portable library where Regex not have support. If at all have Regex support better go for that performance wise

Answer (score 4):

It's the format of the string that you've supplied to Regex.Match.

The correct format would be:

```
Regex.Match(info,@"^\d")
```

The @ means that escape characters (like the backward slash) are treated as normal characters.  Without it your regex would need to be `"^\\d"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong. .Net doesn't use perl-style regexs. The correct expression is @"^\d".

And you should use Regex.IsMatch(...) if you're not going to use the MatchCollection from .Match for anything:

```
RegEx.IsMatch(info, @"^\d")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only trying to find out if the string begins with a number.
Like above, you canskip using regex.
Just use Substring, remove the first character and test if it is a number.

Now if your trying to remove the entire number, then I would convert the string to a char array, and test the chars.

pseudo
string s = ""
for each c in chars{
if c is number then
  s += c
else
  exit for
}
convert the s to an integer, you got the number at the begining of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use Regex (some inteview question platforms do not allow regex ) and `Char.IsDigit(info[0])`,

You can use `if(info[0] => 0 && info[9] <= 9)` to check if char is numeric or not.

Depends on requirements if you do not want to consider `'.'` as Digit (for e.g. Integer values only) do not use `Char.IsDigit(info[0])` since this function returns `true` for `'.'`