# Check if string starts with Regex number

Tags: c#, regex

I'm really new to Regex, so I'm looking for a way to check if my string starts with a certain regex. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372318/c-sharp-string-starts-with-a-number-regex) on the Internet, however, I can't make it work with a custom regex.

I need to know if a specific line starts with

```
3.3. XXX
```

which is how you format German date. So the regex doesn't need to look up only this, but possibly

```
17.4. XXX
```

in both cases, I need to know if the input string starts with a date (which can have two possible notations, as stated above). So, for both it'd return true, however, it wouldn't for this:

```
15G
```

(for example).

Which regex is good to go for this?

Comment: If you are going to parse date, then it's better to use [Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx) or its [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: why do you say that it's a *time* but at the end say that the strings start with a *date*?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I mistakenly wrote this. I edited the post.

Comment: @revo this is stated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not good at parsing number ranges so it can get pretty messy https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504877/1383168

To check if a string is a valid date you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact)

```
string s = "17.4. XXX"; DateTime d;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s.Split(' ')[0], "d.M.", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d)) 
{
    // matches
    Debug.Print($"{d}"); // "4/17/2017 12:00:00 AM"
}
```

Comment: Very nice and clean solution, works perfectly for all the dates and doesn't need manual regex checks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you want a regex for detecting dd.mm type of date this your answer.

```
string testregex = "([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|[0-9])(.)(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[0-9])(.)";
```

you can check any string to find match for this regex, Regex.IsMatch() returns true and statements in if block will execute.

```
string text="17.4 xxxxxx";
if (Regex.IsMatch(string test,testregex))
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: "`give me more clear details in comments`". Don't do this, try to keep your Question updated with all relevant details and examples. **Absolutely though, every regex question should have at least a few examples of what should pass, and what should fail, and why**. It is also fine, after you've updated the question, to reply to an answer that the question has been updated.

Comment: I can see you put`17.4` but not `17.4.`, which is required. As I can see, the dot (.) is missing at the end of the regex. Did you intend to do so? Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: is there always a dot(.) in the end of your target strings? if it is yes, then inform me so I edit the regex in my answer.

Comment: @AliCrash Yes, and it could possibly also be `24.12.`, but the final dot's always there.